# Can relative pronouns reference each other?

Tags: pronouns

Is it grammatically possible to say something like this?:

He was who who he was.

It sounds wrong and it surely doesn't make sense, but could it technically work?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean pronouns in general? Personal pronouns are *I*, *he*, *they* etc. but you used *who* in your example. *who* is an interrogative and a relative pronoun.

Comment: Yes, relative pronouns - that was a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not repeat the *who* and it works.

> He was who he was

is correct. Popeye the Sailor Man is famous for his line "I yam what I yam" [I am what I am]--this works the same way.

"Was" is a linking verb, which is often said to work like an equals sign. So "He = who he was," or "He = the person he was," which makes perfect sense (with the "=" meaning "equaled" rather than "equals").